Compare the amount of points on line segments
We know that a line is an infinite set of points. To compare the amount of elements in two infinite sets, we need to create a mapping between their elements.
For two line segments of different lengths, say line $AB$ and  $CD$, we can create a mapping as below. And thus we created a 1:1 mapping between $X1$ and $X2$. And this mapping exists for all the points on both lines. In this sense, we can say $AB$ and $CD$ have the same amount of points.

Then consider two line segments of the same length, say $AB$ and $EF$ like below. We can use above method to say:

$AB$ and $EG$ have the same amount of points
$AB$ and $GF$ have the same amount of points.

But since $AB$ and $EF$ are of the same length, they must have the same amount of points as well.
So this leads to $EG$ plus $GF$ has the same amount of points as $AB$ while each of them also has the same amount of points as $AB$.
And we can even say all 1-dimenstional lines have the same amount of points.
Is this correct?


Yes. In particular, if two sets have the same infinite cardinality, then their union also has that cardinality.

@GerryMyerson this is really cool, but then why aren't their lengths same if the number of points are?

@Gwen, why don't people weigh the same, if they have the same height? Why don't words mean the same, if they have the same number of letters? Why don't two triangles have the same area, if they have the same perimeter? Length and number of points are two different ways to measure how big something is. They are related, but they aren't the same, and there's no reason to expect them to give the same answers. You are allowing your knowledge of finite sets to determine your thoughts about infinite sets: the union of two (nonempty, disjoint) finite sets has more elements than either set has. But...

...that just doesn't work for infinite sets. There's no reason why what works for finite sets should also work for infinite, and it doesn't.

@Gwen We need to forget our experience/instinct with finite world when entering the infinite. And rely on logic, probably solely. That's the biggest thing I learn so far about infinity.

@GerryMyerson Your comments are invaluable. If you convert them to an answer, I will be more than happy to mark them.
